# MySql 8.0 Aurora RDS not cleaning up idle connections that exceed wait_timeout

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, mysql-8.0

We've recently upgraded from Aurora/RDS MySql 5.6 to 8.0.  We're now seeing that our sleeping processes that are idle for more than the defined 250s `wait_timeout` and 250s `interactive_timeout` are not being cleaned up.  Additionally, it doesn't even seem to be an issue with incorrectly setting those values, because the default of 28800 (8hrs) is also surpassed and isn't cleaned up.

It appears that the AWS RDS/Aurora process isn't cleaning this up for 8.0, but it does just fine in 5.6.

UPDATE:  We've been informed by the Aurora team at AWS that the issue has been identified as an issue with the Aurora engine version 3.  It will take some time to patch, and for now we will be implementing a work-around by scheduling manual clean-up of idle processes that have exceeded the timeout duration.

Comment: Aurora is not MySQL, because AWS has made significant changes to the MySQL code. Does this help explain: https://ahmedahamid.com/amazon-aurora-mysql-and-wait-timeout/

Comment: @BillKarwin we read that article, as well. The odd thing is our 5.6 is also in Aurora and it works there.  Additionally, we're not setting the session value of either of those which I would assume means that it's using the parameter group's version.

Comment: Well, my usual answer to all things AWS is to ask AWS. You're paying for the service to be supported, so hold them to account and make them explain it. I admit AWS Support is usually rubbish, but keep escalating until you get an answer.

Comment: Appreciate that, yeah, we have an engineer call scheduled, but I figured I give this a shot as well.  Thanks.